# How to connect Android with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to connect Android system with PHP and MySQL to create a simple login activity. I am using genymotion emulator running on 4.2 Android version.

I am using the thread in my code to make it run in the background, and using JSON to get back the data in a smooth way.

But the problem is that the system crash and force close. If anyone can help me i will appreciate that.

## log cat

```
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at pack.coderzheaven.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:65)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at pack.coderzheaven.AndroidPHPConnectionDemo$CheckLogin$1.run(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.java:118)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-02 21:29:46.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1363):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## JSONParser.java

```
package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
        /*
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }
            */
             if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

## AndroidPHPConnectionDemo

```
package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidPHPConnectionDemo extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText et, pass;
    String Username, Password;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    private static final String url_check_login = "http://10.0.3.2/check.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PERSON = "person";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_pass = "password";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // login();

                // Getting complete person details in background thread
                new CheckLogin().execute();

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete person details
     * */
    class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading person details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting person details in background thread
         * */

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting person details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that person details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_check_login, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single person Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received person details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PERSON); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject person = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            et.setText(person.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            pass.setText(person.getString(TAG_pass));

                            Log.e("success in login", "SUCCESS IN LOGIN");

                        }

                        else {
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

## check.php

```
<?php

require_once('db_config.php'); 


// array for JSON response
$response = array();


//if(isset($_GET['Username'])and isset($_POST['Password'])){

  if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
//   $username = $_POST['Username'];
//   $password = $_POST['Password'];

     $pid = $_GET['pid'];   

//   $query_search = "select username, password from members where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";

     $query_search = "select from members where pid = '".$pid."'";   

     $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

   if (mysql_num_rows($query_exec) > 0) 
   {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec);

        $person = array();
        $person['username']=$result[username];
        $person['password']=$result['password'];

   // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

   // user node
        $response["person"] = array();

        array_push($response["person"], $person);

   // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
    else
    {
   // no user found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No User found";

   // echo no users JSON
           echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else 
{
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}    
?>
```

Comment: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadExceptio` What did you learn when you Googled for this exception or searched on here before you asked a question?

Comment: no sir this is my first time asking about this specific problem do not judge me  right-away

Comment: Why does being your first time mean that you do not have to search before asking a question?

Comment: man what is wrong with you after i searched and tried many times to solve this problem i did not get success with it so i asked here so can you help me or you will try to analyse my this answer too ?
my first asking this question on stackoverflow  that what i meant

Comment: Friendly tip: I would also investigate protection against sql injection for your PHP code - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Have you read the thread which I linked?  People get annoyed because this question is asked several times every day.  A simple search before you post is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the runOnUiThread inside the AsyncTask.  You're getting the exception because you're tying up the UI thread for too long. Using an AsyncTask is the right thing to do, but you're calling runOnUiThread from within it, which doesn't make sense because then it is no longer asynchronous.

1. Remove the runOnUiThread portion of it from within the
   doInBackground().
2. Keep the values you want to display on the screen
   as members of the async task or as the results template param.
3. Put the setText calls in the postExecute, because that is run on the UI
   thread.

Something like this:

```
/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete person details
 * */
class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    JSONArray productObj;

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading person details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting person details in background thread
     * */

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting person details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that person details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_check_login, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single person Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received person details
                        productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PERSON); // JSON Array

                    }

                    else {
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details


        if ( productObj != null ) {
            // get first product object from JSON Array
            JSONObject person = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

            et.setText(person.getString(TAG_NAME));
            pass.setText(person.getString(TAG_pass));

            Log.e("success in login", "SUCCESS IN LOGIN");
        }

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```