# Android connected with PHP and MySQL using asynctask, but getting errors

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

I am creating a login activity that need connection between `Android` and PHP `MySQL` so I used `AsyncTask` and `JSON` but the problem is that the system force clause and display in the logCat errors. Can anyone help me to fix this error?

This is line 124 : `Log.d("Single person Details", json.toString());`.

## log cat

```
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at pack.coderzheaven.AndroidPHPConnectionDemo$CheckLogin.doInBackground(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.java:124)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at pack.coderzheaven.AndroidPHPConnectionDemo$CheckLogin.doInBackground(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.java:1)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-03 14:24:54.668: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     ... 4 more
02-03 14:24:55.008: E/JSON Parser(1588): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value You of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

## JSONParser.java

```
package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
        /*
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }
            */
             if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

## AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.java

```
package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidPHPConnectionDemo extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText et, pass;
    String Username, Password;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single person url
    // ******************************************************************

    // the localhost in the genymotion emulator = 10.0.3.2
    // ******************************************************************
    private static final String url_check_login = "http://10.0.3.2/check.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PERSON = "person";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_pass = "password";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // login();

                // Getting complete person details in background thread
                new CheckLogin().execute();

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete person details
     * */
    class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        JSONArray productObj;

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading person details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting person details in background thread
         * */

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting person details by making HTTP request
                // Note that person details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_login,
                        "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single person Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received person details
                    productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PERSON); // JSON Array

                     JSONObject

                }

                else {
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            if (productObj != null) {
                try {
                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject person = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    et.setText(person.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    pass.setText(person.getString(TAG_pass));

                    Log.e("success in login", "SUCCESS IN LOGIN");

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

## check.php

```
    <?php

    require_once('db_config.php'); 


    // array for JSON response
    $response = array();


    //if(isset($_GET['Username'])and isset($_POST['Password'])){

      if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
    //   $username = $_POST['Username'];
    //   $password = $_POST['Password'];

         $pid = $_GET['pid'];   

    //   $query_search = "select username, password from members where username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'";

         $query_search = "select from members where pid = '".$pid."'";   

         $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

       if (mysql_num_rows($query_exec) > 0) 
       {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec);

            $person = array();
            $person['username']=$result[username];
            $person['password']=$result['password'];

       // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

       // user node
            $response["person"] = array();

            array_push($response["person"], $person);

       // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);

        }
        else
        {
       // no user found
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "No User found";

       // echo no users JSON
               echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }   


?>
```

Comment: Which one is line 124 in AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.java?

Comment: This is nearly the same (but not the same error, I notice) as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516693/how-to-connect-android-with-php-and-mysql). A general tip is, where you ask a question that might be (incorrectly) regarded as a duplicate, you add a post script to your question showing how it is different. Also, as per the other question, have you searched for the error message? What debugging have you done?

Comment: The PHP has a SQL injection vulnerability in it, by the way. Switch to PDO or MySQLi if you can, and use parameterisation.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$person['username']=$result[username];
                            ^-------^--- missing ' quotes
```

is going to produce a PHP warning due to the use unquoted array keys. If your PHP errors are visible to the world, you'll get

```
PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant blah blah blahYOUR JSON DATA HERE
```

as output, which will then cause a JSON parse error in your client app.

If your client is expecting nothing but pure JSON text, then you have to **ENSURE** that your server-side code can producing NOTHING but pure json. Anything else breaks the whole process.

Comment: @ MARC B  what did you mean i did not understand your solution thank you for your reply